# Solving complex equation numerically

Tags: equation-solving, numerics, complex, numerical-value

I'm trying to solve the following equation for $z$ for a set of given *complex* values of $a$ and for fixed $b$ (without providing any initial guess value(s)):

$2^{iz}~\Gamma\left(\dfrac{iz+b}{2}+1\right)\Gamma\left(\dfrac{iz-b+1}{2}\right) = a $

I've already tried with [Solve](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html), [NSolve](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolve.html) and [NSolveValues](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NSolveValues.html), but no result is being produced!

```
b = 5;
a = 1.2 + 2.0I;
Solve[2^(I z) Gamma[(I z+b)/2+1] Gamma[(I z-b+1)/2] == a, z]
NSolve[2^(I z) Gamma[(I z+b)/2+1] Gamma[(I z-b+1)/2] == a, z]
NSolveValues[2^(I z) Gamma[(I z+b)/2+1] Gamma[(I z-b+1)/2] == a, z]
```

**Output:** Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients or the system obtained by direct rationalization of inexact numbers present in the system. Since many of the methods used by Solve require exact input, providing Solve with an exact version of the system may help.

And the other two methods aren't producing any results!

Same problem is there even if I split this expression using natural logarithm:

$iz\ln{2} + \ln\left[\Gamma \left(\dfrac{iz+b}{2}+1\right)\right] + \ln\left[\Gamma \left(\dfrac{iz-b+1}{2}\right)\right] = \ln{a} $

So now how to solve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way is

```
b = 5;a = 1.2 + 2.0I;NSolve[2^(I z) Gamma[(I z + b)/2 + 1] Gamma[(I z - b + 1)/2] == a && 
Re[z] >= -5 && Re[z] <= 5 && Im[z] >= -5 &&  Im[z] <= 5, z, Complexes]
```

> `{{z->-4.90799-3.04034 I},{z->-2.66851-1.46792 I},{z->-0.662739+0.308154 I},{z->1.26622 -0.268927 I},{z->3.38646 -2.01853 I}}`

Comment: `Solve[2^(I z) Gamma[(I z + b)/2 + 1] Gamma[(I z - b + 1)/2] == a && 
Re[z] >= -5 && Re[z] <= 5 && Im[z] >= -5 &&  Im[z] <= 5, z, Complexes]` produces the same result.

Answer (score 3):

When the other methods fail you will need to use [`FindRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html) and provide initial estimates.

```
b = 5;
a = 1.2 + 2.0 I // Rationalize;

f[z_] = 2^(I z) Gamma[(I z + b)/2 + 1] Gamma[(I z - b + 1)/2] - a;

sol = (FindRoot[f[z] == 0, {z, #},
       WorkingPrecision -> 15] // N) & /@
   {1 + I, 1 - I, -1 + I, -1 - I} // Union

(* {{z -> -0.662739 + 0.308154 I}, {z -> 0.0374761 + 2.02576 I}, {z -> 
   1.26622 - 0.268927 I}} *)

2^(I z) Gamma[(I z + b)/2 + 1] Gamma[(I z - b + 1)/2] == a /. sol

(* {True, True, True} *)
```